# Python not printing output in pycharm console

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am trying to fetch some info from YT using Selenium with python. The code seems ok, however its not printing output in the console.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@CorporateMusician")
driver.maximize_window()
videos= driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'style-scope ytd-rich-grid-renderer')
for video in videos:
    title= video.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="video-title"]').text,
    views= video.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text,
    posted=video.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
    print(title)
```

Comment: Does it work as expected if you run it from a regular terminal window instead of pycharm?

Comment: No, its not printing anything.

Comment: Are you sure `videos` is finding anything? Put `print(len(videos))` before the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if YouTube DOM is the same for every locations, but it seemed like you're getting text from wrong element.

Locator of video container for me looks like `ytd-shelf-renderer #items #dismissible`

Title is it's child `h3`, views and posted are present in `#metadata-line`.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@CorporateMusician")
driver.maximize_window()
videos= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ytd-shelf-renderer #items #dismissible')
for video in videos:
    title = video.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'h3').text,
    metadata = video.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#metadata-line span')
    views = metadata[0].text,
    posted = metadata[1].text
    print(title)
    print(views)
    print(posted)
    print('___________________')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Yaroslavm. Could you tell me what is the use of metadata = video.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#metadata-line span'). I really dont understand , why are we using this.

Comment: @Sumanto https://monosnap.com/file/W4YO5lpBZHS5yj0X31ugbk7rir7fVR views and posted text is placed in `#metadata-line` container with 2 spans.
So, to get views and posted, you just need to get `#metadata-line` container and get 2 spans from it. Then you just get text from each span.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/@CorporateMusician")
driver.maximize_window()

# Wait for the videos to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # Waiting for up to 10 seconds
videos = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'style-scope ytd-rich-grid-renderer')))

for video in videos:
    try:
        title = video.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]').text
        views = video.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text
        posted = video.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
        print(title, views, posted)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data: {e}")

driver.quit()
```

If the code encounters an exception before reaching the print(title), nothing will be printed to the console. Consider adding a try-except block to catch any exceptions and print them.

Comment: If it gets an exception and there's no `try/except` the default exception handler prints the error message.